# Encrypt & Decrypt String Routine ASM x86

Tags: assembly, encryption, cryptography, x86

Basically I'm trying to create a program that encrypts an input string & then decrypts it back to it's original state using ASM x86.

The program accepts an encryption key (referred to as EKey in the program) which is a random char and then encrypts a 6 character string so far.

I'm having trouble writing the decrypt function. I started off by just reversing each line of the encryption (push ecx changed to pop ecx, etc) but have been advised that that's not correct.

Here's the main encryption function:

```
void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey){
char temp_char;                     // char temporary store

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    // encrypt characters one at a time
{
    temp_char = OChars [i];         //
    __asm {                         //
        push   eax                  // save register values on stack to be safe
        push   ecx                  //
                                    //
        movzx  ecx,temp_char        // set up registers (Nb this isn't StdCall or Cdecl)
        lea    eax,EKey             //
        call   encrypt              // encrypt the character
        mov    temp_char,al         //
                                    //
        pop    ecx                  // restore original register values from stack
        pop    eax                  //
    }
    EChars [i] = temp_char;         // Store encrypted char in the encrypted chars array
}
```

return;

And the subroutine 'encrypt':

```
       encrypt: push esi
              push ecx
              mov  esi, eax
              and dword ptr[esi], 0xFF
              ror byte ptr[esi], 1
              ror byte ptr[esi], 1
              add byte ptr[esi], 0x01
              mov ecx, [esi]
              pop edx
          x17 : ror dl, 1
                dec ecx
                jnz x17
                mov eax, edx
                add eax, 0x20
                xor eax, 0xAA
                pop esi
                ret
```

Inputs:
Register EAX = 32-bit address of Ekey,
Register ECX = the character to be encrypted (in the low 8-bit field, CL)

Output: 
Register EAX = the encrypted value of the source character (in the low 8-bit field, AL).

Could somebody please tell me (or point me to somewhere I can find out) which lines need reversing for the decryption function?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Thje question is: is your encyption algorithm reversible?

Comment: You can't revert an algorithm by writing the assembly instruction in the reverse order. It just does not work like that. You should instead know which high-level steps are done to encrypt your data and revert those high  level steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
decrypt: push   esi
         push   ecx
         mov    esi, eax
         and    dword ptr [esi], 0xFF
         ror    byte ptr [esi], 1
         ror    byte ptr [esi], 1
         add    byte ptr [esi], 1
         mov    ecx, [esi]
         pop    eax
         xor    eax, 0xAA
         sub    eax, 0x20
         and    eax, 0xFF
   x18:  rol    al, 1
         dec    ecx
         jnz    x18
         pop    esi
         ret
```

Why do you do this in assembly?  You can emulate left and right bit rotations with shift operators or table lookups.